# Using aparcstats2table program in Freesurfer to extract the stats data for multiple subjects

Tags: python

I’m trying to extract the statistical data for multiple subjects using the aparcstats2table program in freesurfer.

I used this command to extract the statistical data for one subject.

```
aparcstats2table --subjects /fefs1/fcit/ezahamalyoubi/freesurfer/subjects/MCI_Female_Subjects/I4688/ --hemi lh --meas volume --parc=aparc --tablefile=I4688_lh_volume.txt
```

How can I edit this command to work for many subjects and store the statistical data in one txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the list of subjects to the '--subjects' option:

```
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/fefs1/fcit/ezahamalyoubi/freesurfer/subjects/MCI_Female_Subjects
SUBJ=$(ls ${SUBJECTS_DIR} | grep -v fsaverage)

echo "Extracting stats for ${SUBJ}"

aparcstats2table --subjects ${SUBJ} --hemi lh --meas volume --parc=aparc --tablefile=lh_volume.txt
```